# Python: Why doesn't second loop work?

Tags: python, regex

can anyone tell me why doesn't the second loop which is supposed to count the number of lines work ? I am new to Python and programming so it's quite confusing.

```
import re
number_lines=0
file=open('c:/users/jakub piotr/desktop/mbox-short.txt',"r")

number=(sum([int(x) for line in file for x in re.findall('^New.+: ([0-9]+)',line)]))
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("New Revision:"):
        number_lines+=1
print(number/number_lines)
```

Comment: can you share couple of sample lines from file as well

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What loop are you talking about specifically and what is not working about it? Are you getting an error or is it just not looping through it?

Comment: I don't see a second loop.

Comment: `file` is an iterator, and after the first loop (inside the `sum`) it is already exhausted. Open the file anew, store in it a list, or rewind it with `seek`. Looking for dupe target...

Comment: I think he is pointing to for loop outside list-comprehension

Comment: You have consumed the lines in your list comprehension, since you have not saved the lines to a variable with let's say file.readlines(), you now have the File Pointer on the end of the file, so there are no more lines to read.

Comment: Thank you so much guys ! I did not know you can actually exhaust an iterator. It helped me to figure it out !